# Is there a way to hide metadata like the name of software/application that produced a pdf?

Tags: adobe-indesign, metadata

When exporting a pdf with InDesign or Illustrator, the file includes metadata like the name of the software that was used to generate it.
I would like to know if it is possible to hide or edit the metadata included in the exported pdf file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Acrobat...

`Tools > Protection > Sanitize Document` will remove metadata such as creation software, dates, etc.

Before...

[image]

After...

[image]

You can also use the `Remove Hidden Information` option under the `Tools > Protection` menu.

*Without* Acrobat.. I have no idea.

Comment: Alright, seems to be what i need. Thank you, i'll try that